# How redirect in js after select value from option select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in web development.
I have this code:

```
<select class="selectpicker indexSelect10 filterMenu10  callendarFilter callendarFilterCategory" name="sortAfter">
    <option value="lang/pl">PL</option>
    <option value="lang/de">DE</option>
    <option value="lang/en">EN</option>
</select>
```

In values I have url address. After selected values I want to redirect user to url from option value: domain.com/lang/en

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to assign an `onchange` event listener to the `<select>`. The redirect itself works by using `location = some_full_url;`

Comment: can you write me sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// $(el).on("change") will listen whenever the select has new value
$("select").on("change", function(){
    // if select value changed
    var id = $(this).val() // get select value
    window.location.href = "/new/url/route?id=" + id // redirect to somewhere
})
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation what your code does to make the answer more useful

Comment: And you probably meant to write `var value = ...`